"Built input file cannot be found: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib"
I am building a XCode 15, IOS 17.5 project with Swift. I installed with TesseractOCRiOS Github with Cocoapod. This library is pretty old and stopped maintaining around IOS 6. However, after fixing mountains of errors, I reached one that I am stuck on:
"Build input file cannot be found: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?"
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)
Well I got some other errors like "Multiple commands produced" or whatever, and I solved those by adding a script that deletes any duplicate files in the Podfile. Then after that, when I try to build the project, it started giving me "Build input file cannot be found" errors.

Libstdc++ isn't supported anymore, you need to change the configuration to use libc++

thanks for the reply! how do i change it to libc++?

It's in the project settings
